# Ideals of $L^1(G)$ and normal subgroups of $G$

Tags: gr.group-theory, fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. Is there any correspondence between closed two-sided ideals of $L^1(G)$ and closed normal subgroups of $G$? (Especially, is there any correspondence between finite codimension closed two-sided ideals of $L^1(G)$ and closed normal subgroups of $G$?)

Comment: Note that there is a correspondence between finite dim reps of $G$ and finite codim ideals of $L^1(G)$. However, thre is no correspondence between f.d reps and subgroups.

Comment: I will reiterate what Uri has said: in my opinion and in my experience, there is no meaningful general correspondence of the kind you seek. Playing around with finite cyclic groups of prime order should illustrate this

Comment: For finite cyclic groups you do better working over Q.

Comment: You can get a correspondence in the case of ordinary group algebras by using hopf ideals.

Comment: @ Benjamin Steinberg: thanks, but I need to G be an infinite locally compact group.

Comment: Mr/Mrs Pseudonym: how is your last comment relevant to @BenjaminSteinberg's comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is about the best you can hope for, I think.

For discrete groups a homomorphism between groups gives rise to a homomorphism between algebras. So although we do not have a "correspondence", in this setting a normal subgroup $N\lhd G$ gives rise to an ideal $J_N:= \ker( \ell^1(G) \to \ell^1(G/N))$. A simple cardinality argument shows you that $J_N$ is usually much bigger than $\ell^1(N)$.

As I said in my comment, in general there can be many more ideals.

For locally compact groups, the functorial properties of $G\mapsto L^1(G)$ are not so good. But if I recall correctly, when $N\lhd G$ is a *closed* normal subgroup then we still obtain a well-defined, continuous algebra homomorphism $L^1(G)\to L^1(G/N)$, and hence its kernel $J_N$ will still be a closed $2$-sided ideal in $L^1(G)$.

Comment: Thanks...Are there any conditions for group G that I conclude the inverse of your answer? I mean, is there any condition for G which some two-sided ideals of $L^(G)$, introduce closed normal subgroups of G?

Comment: @Albertharold For the reasons I explained above, I doubt if there are any groups for which _all_ closed ideals in $L^1(G)$ arise from closed normal subgroups of $G$. On the other hand, you _could_ perhaps try to find a criterion for a given ideal in $L^1(G)$ to be $J_N$ for some subgroup -- I suspect this may have been considered by people like Reiter, a long time ago